# How to uninstall wrong Tensorflow version?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I commit a silly mistake and installed the wrong version of Tensorflow (I'm using windows but installed the mac version). How do I uninstall the wrong version?
Also I found out that Tensorflow can only be installed in the Python 3.5 version(mine is 3.6), is that true? How to downgrade my Python without losing all libraries?

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 0.12.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\eleut\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
Requires: protobuf, wheel, numpy, six
```

Comment: `pip3 uninstall tensorflow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To uninstall tensorflow just use this command:**

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
```

**TensorFlow with Python3.6**

It should work because ticket https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6533
is closed. You just need to install tensorflow once again and it should work under python3.6:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

If not use the following instructions:

**"Downgrade" to python3.5**

You can't just change python version, because some libraries can be incompatible with python3.5.
You should save current libraries versions in file using this command:

```
pip3 freeze > ./requirements.txt
```

**Python3.5 installation**

If you have only python3.6 and want to install python3.5 easily you can use pyenv (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and create virtualenv with python3.5 using instructions from pyenv tutorial.

**Installing libraries from python3.6**

Make sure that your virtualenv with python3.5 is activated. You should have name of this virtualenv visible in bash prompt. Make sure that your python version is 3.5 using this command:

```
python --version
```

After that you can install libraries from your python3.6 using this command:

```
pip3 install -r <path to requirements.txt file>
```

**If installation fails:**

If installation fails for some packages, just edit requirements.txt by removing version from this file. For example if version 2.0 of some_package does't work under python3.5 then change line from requirements.txt:

```
some_package==2.0
```

to:

```
some_package
```

save changes and run once again

```
pip3 install -r <path to requirements.txt file>
```

Comment: Got the following issue trying to install it like you suggest `C:\Users\eleut>pip3 install tensorflow

    Collecting tensorflow

    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )

    No matching distribution found for tensorflow` Any thoughts about why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe it is because of other installed packages. Try to create new virtualenv with python3.6 and install tensorflow. I just successfully installed tensorflow under python3.6 on Debian Jessie. If still tensorflow is not found try to install python3.5 using instructions in my post

Answer (score 0):

Just use: `pip3 uninstall tensorflow`